# Calling WebAPI with authorisation from server side blazor

Tags: authorization, blazor, server-side, webapi

Apologies if this is a bit of a dumb question - I'm trying to get my head round security setup and don't have much experience in this area.  Been reading as much as I can, but can't find a clear example for what I'm trying to do.

I have created the default server-side and wasm blazor projects from the visual studio templates, and have shared the wasm project so I can re-use both client-side and server-side as per Carl Franklin's article:

http://www.appvnext.com/blog/2020/2/2/reuse-blazor-wasm-ui-in-blazor-server

That all works fine.

Next, I repeat, but add the "Individual User Accounts" option to both projects when creating, set the db string to a shared identity database. Both work individually, however, when I share the client code, and call from server-side blazor, the webapi call fails with an "unauthorized" error.

So, in short, I'm logging into the server-side blazor project successfully.  The failure happens when I attempt to call the webapi which now sits in a separate project (the WASM project) and so will run in a different domain (don't think I'm hitting cors problems yet). When I attempt to call the webapi I get the unauthorized error.  When I run in WASM, it all works as expected.

Can someone please give me a pointer on what steps I need to take to get this working?  Full code for the razor component is below...

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using BlazorWasm.Shared
@attribute [Authorize]
@inject HttpClient Http

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "https://localhost:44378/WeatherForecast";
            forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>(url);
        }
        catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
        {
            exception.Redirect();
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException exception)
        {
            string msg = exception.Message;
        }
    }

}
```